# what's the relation in storage aspect for virtual server, image, block device, image template in softlayer?

Tags: block, virtual, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When create image template from an existed virtual server, first need to get the block device ID of existed virtual server, and then virtual server ID and block device ID will be used to create image template.

Q: What is the meaning of block device? What does block device used for? Does every virtual server has a block device ID? Is block device is unique to each virtual server?

Can anyone give a storage graph to show the whole relations for virtual server/image/image template/block device?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block devices represent the disks in a server, when you take a image from a virtual server you need to specify which disks or block devices you want include in the image template, for example when you want a image template from a Server which contains 5 disks but you only want that your image template has the disk where the OS has been installed. So as you can see each block device is unique for each server.

Regards